# httpsrequest google drive refreshtoken

Tags: .net, vb.net, httpwebrequest, google-drive-api

I'm trying to create a http request to get a new accesstoken with the stored refreshtoken so I can access Google Drive.

```
   Dim uri As String = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"

   Dim para As String = "code='" + cred.RefreshToken + "'&client_id='" + ClientCredentials.CLIENT_ID + "'&client_secret='" + ClientCredentials.CLIENT_SECRET + "'&grant_type='refresh_token'"

   Dim httpWebRequest As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = Net.WebRequest.Create(uri)
   httpWebRequest.Method = "POST"
   httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

   Dim requestStream As System.IO.Stream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
   Dim streamwriter As System.IO.StreamWriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter(requestStream)
   streamwriter.Write(para)
   streamwriter.Close()

   Dim httpWebResponse As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = httpWebRequest.GetResponse()
```

But this returns a bad request. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

You are not writing your credentials to the StreamWriter, it should read...

```
streamwriter.Write(para)
```

That's assuming they are correct of course.

Comment: I'm sorry that's a typo. What else could send a bad request (400) ?